# Using Artifactory to proxy Cypress with CYPRESS_DOWNLOAD_MIRROR

Tags: cypress, artifactory

**Desired behavior**

I would like to use CYPRESS_DOWNLOAD_MIRROR pointing toward my artifactory configuration for Cypress and just be able to do npm install and download library AND binary of Cypress

**Current behavior**

When setting Cypress in artifactory, and downloading it with CYPRESS_DOWNLOAD_MIRROR set toward this tool, the download script find binary files as X.Y.Z and not cypress.zip and fail. Apparently I can't rename binaries in artifactory. It seems to have made it available in a name X.Y.Z instead of cypress.zip

My artifactory admin tell me to do this command before but I can't since it's a post action of Cypress
curl –v « https://artifactory.mycompany.fr/artifactory/remote-download.cypress-generic/desktop/6.8.0?platform=win32&arch=x64 » > cypress.zip

**Workaround**

For now, I'm using CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY to point to a manually uploaded binary in artifactory but it's a pain because I have to separate Linux binary (for CI) and Windows binary (for dev) and if my package is configured with "cypress": "^6.2.1" the npm library will go to 6.2.1 and my binary will stuck to 6.2.0 for example...

Debug logs

Installing Cypress (version: 6.8.0)

× Downloading Cypress
→ Cypress Version: 6.8.0
Unzipping Cypress
Finishing Installation
The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading
Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration

Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

URL: https://artifactory.mycompany.fr/artifactory/remote-download.cypress.io/desktop/6.8.0?platform=win32&arch=x64
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Download method

```
npm
```

Operating System

Linux

```
Windows
```

Other

```
I'm behind a proxy
```

I don't really know if it's an artifactory or a Cypress matter but I need help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work on Windows using the following:

I created a generic remote repository, making sure it is pointing to https://download.cypress.io, and under the advanced tab, added the query params: platform=win32&arch=x64  (notice there is a dedicated field for it).

The above is required in order to cache the correct binary based on the OS and arch (you might require a different remote repository with different query params).
I found it on Cypress doc that these query params control the binary type which will be downloaded (so we need to make sure it fits the client os and arch).

In the .npmrc I simply provided the following:
CYPRESS_DOWNLOAD_MIRROR=https://user:myverystrongpassword@myartifactory/artifactory/generic-cypress-windows

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this way. I'll have to separate Windows and linux binaries but it's doable

Comment: *generic remote repository* - what do you mean by that in more detail?

Comment: I mean that the repository type created on Artifactory in order to download the Cypress package must be of type generic repo.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to accepted answer, it is possible to replace pre-defined 'Query Params' with enabling 'Propagate Query Params'. If set, the query params passed with the request to Artifactory, will be passed on to the remote repo.

Please note, according to [JFrog docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/Advanced+Settings), this setting is only available for Generic type repositories.

Comment: It seems Artifactory does pass through params but it stores the file without the notion of those params, it will be just /desktop/13.7.0 which means whatever platform was requested first will be cached, and if the same version for another platform is requested a wrong file will be downloaded... sucks

Comment: Oh, a solution to this is to ditch the query param-based approach and use CYPRESS_DOWNLOAD_PATH_TEMPLATE while pointing to https://cdn.cypress.io in this case binaries structured by platform and arch in artifactory repo.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this command (on MacOS) to directly pass path to downloaded Cypress.zip file

```bash
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=~/Downloads/cypress.zip yarn add cypress --D
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mirror the https://cdn.cypress.io, the one that https://download.cypress.io redirects to.